# cordova get device UUID globally

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins

i am using cordova plugin in one of my app,i am need a device UUId,device unique id and i want to use it globally,i am able to get it inside the onDeviceReady() function,but i am unable to use it globally need help.

```
var deviceName
var deviceUID
var deviceOs
var deviceOsVersion
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false)
function onDeviceReady() {
deviceName = device.name;
deviceUID = device.uuid;
deviceOs = device.platform;
deviceOsVersion = device.version;
//Use device information as required
// userDetails(deviceUID);
console.log("devicename : " + deviceName + " deviceId: " + deviceUID + " deviceOs: " + deviceOs + " deviceosversion : " + deviceOsVersion);

 }
   //Use device information as required
   // userDetails(deviceUID);
  console.log("devicename : " + deviceName + " deviceId: " + deviceUID + "     deviceOs: " + deviceOs + " deviceosversion : " + deviceOsVersion);
```

Comment: store device id in window.localstorage, then you will access it whenever you want

Comment: @Nikil As Divyesh suggested use window.localstorage for persisting it even after closing the application, else you can also make use of window.sessionstorage to retain it temporarily till you close the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To SET item

```
window.localStorage.setItem("uuid", deviceUID);
```

To GET item value

```
window.localStorage.getItem("uuid");
```

To REMOVE value

```
localStorage.removeItem("uuid");
```

or even

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Remember you need `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` in you index.html

Comment: thanks for u r replay,but its still  undefiend even after i use this.when i land on the page it fires first consol.log(window.localStorage.getItem("uuid")); den goes to my ondeviceready function.